# NestJS - No response getById request

Tags: typescript, get, nestjs

I need your help. I recently started learning the nestjs framework. I am currently trying to do CRUD operations without a database. I have 2 methods: getAllUsers and getDifferentUser. I manage to get all users, but I can't get a user by id. I don't get any error, 200 response, but my response is empty. What is my mistake? Thank you very much

userService.ts

```
public getAllUsers(): IUserModel[] {
   return this.users;
}

public findDifferentUser(id: number): IUserModel {
   return this.users.find(user => user.id === id);
}
```

user.controller.ts

```
@Controller('users')
export class UserController {

   constructor(private userService: UserService) {}

   @Get()
   public getAllUsers(): IUserModel[] {
      return this.userService.getAllUsers();
   }

   @Get(':id')
   public getDifferentUser(@Param('id') id: number): IUserModel {
      return this.userService.findDifferentUser(id);
   }
}
```

user.model.ts

```
export interface IUserModel {
   id: number;
   name: string;
   age: number;
   description: string;
   quality: string;
}
```

Comment: are you sure that `id` at `getDifferentUser` is a number? everything you use `@Query()` or `@Param()`, the value will be a string. Unless you use something like `ValidationPipe` with `transform: true`

Comment: I can only say that `this.userService.findDifferentUser(id)` is returning `undefined`.

Comment: @MicaelLevi, I have static array where id is a number. I am new into nextjs (2 days). What should I do with this problem? And one more question: id should be string or number? In database and static array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this in your controller:

```
 @Get(':id')
   public getDifferentUser(@Param('id', ParseIntPipe) id: number): IUserModel {
      return this.userService.findDifferentUser(id);
   }
```

Because you need to convert `id` to a number. When you recieve it in param, it's a `string`.

- As a general rule, for any requests, regardless of the programming language, `parameters` and `queryParamaters` are always strings.
- You need to handle them in your code and convert them to the format you want. In your case, parse the value to an integer.
- In NestJs, you can leverage the use of `DTOs`. And use them in your query parameters. Something like this:

```
  @Get('exams/:examId/query')
  async getAllExamData(
    @Param('examId', new ParseIntPipe()) examId: number,
    @Query() data: ExamQueryDto,
  ) { 
   // write your logic here to handle whatever you need
  }
```

And the `ExamQueryDto` will look similar to this, based on your use case:

```
import {  Type } from 'class-transformer';
import { IsBoolean, IsInt, IsOptional } from 'class-validator';

export class ExamQueryDto {
  @IsOptional()
  @IsInt()
  @Type(() => Number)
  userId?: number;

  @IsOptional()
  @IsInt()
  @Type(() => Number)
  examAttemptId?: number;

  @IsOptional()
  @IsBoolean()
  @Type(() => Boolean)
  reviewSubmissions: boolean;
}
```

Notice the use of `class-transformer`, which transforms the data recieved from the query, into the type you want. For example `string -> number`.

- DTOs are great. Also make use of them in your `@Body()` when your request has a body. If you send the body in `JSON` format, the data type will be preserved and you wont need to convert it, but the DTO will help you pass these bits of data to other functions. And you can use it like this `myAwesomeDto.userId` for example.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works) I have a question about this. Why am I getting a string here even though my array with id field is a number? And in general, how to correctly record the id in the database and even for static data: in the form of a tape or in the form of a number?

Comment: You are most welcome. As a general rule, for any requests, regardless of the programming language, `parameters` and `queryParamaters` are always strings.

You need to handle them in your code and convert them to the format you want. In your case, parse the value to an integer. I will add this to the response, and write a bit more in case someone needs it.